# Upstart task to wait for iscsi target to become available?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, iscsi, upstart

I've got a couple of virtualization servers running Ubuntu 12.04 and Virtualbox and just bought a Synology NAS which I plan to use as an iSCSI target to serve storage for the VMs.  I realize that enterprise installations with backup generators and staff have to worry about this, but I want my whole setup to come up automatically in sequence if everything was powered off and I just went down the rack hitting power buttons.  So before my init scripts launch the VMs they'd have to wait for the Synology box with its iSCSI targets to become available.

Before I reinvent the wheel, does anyone have an Upstart script that waits (with a timeout) for an iSCSI target to become available?

Comment: Why are you "going down the rack hitting buttons"? Set the auto restart on powerloss, with a 2 minute delay, in the BIOS of your servers.

Comment: I do actually have the servers set to power on after power comes back, never noticed an option to add a delay to that, will have to check.  But I thought it would be a better practice to have the VM servers really check/wait for the NAS to become available before they try to start the VMs.